# React - token refresh is being executed in wrong order

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I'm quite new to React, and I've been helping to solve an issue in our project with React. The JWT token is expiring before some of the actions, and we need to refresh it using the JWT refresh token, before executing the "final" call we were going to execute originally.

Code would be similar to this one:

```
 mainFunction() {
    [...]
    if (!userTokenIsValid) {
       updateUserToken();
    }
    executeWhateverNeedsPermission();
    [...]
 }

 function userTokenIsValid() {
   if (!localStorage.userToken) return null;
   return (jwt.decode(localStorage.userToken).expiry > 30);
 }

 function getNewUserToken() {
   if (!localStorage.userToken) return null;
    return rp({
        uri: API_URL + "/token/refresh",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.refreshToken
        },
        json: true
    }).then((data) => {
        if (!data || !data.userToken) {
            localStorage.removeItem('userToken')
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token);
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Something went wrong: " + error);
        throw error;
    });
 }
```

I'd be expecting the code above to be executed in order, so checking the token and requesting a new one if necessary, and then executing the request to the API.

But, in those cases where the token is expired, then I can see this order:

401  /admin/resources
200  /api/token/refresh

As said, I'm quite new to this, I think I should change the code to use promises, but every trial I gave didn't work (because of my newbie code, I must admit). Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are calling `getNewUserToken` inside `updateUserToken`. With that code `executeWhateverNeedsPermission` is going to be called before the promise created by `rp` is completed. So you need to call `executeWhateverNeedsPermission` when the promise has been resolved. You can do something like this:

```
function mainFunction() {
  // [...]
  if (!userTokenIsValid()) {
    updateUserToken().then(() => executeWhateverNeedsPermission());
  } else {
    executeWhateverNeedsPermission();
  }
  // [...]
}
```

Or improving the code a little using async/await:

```
async function mainFunction() {
  // [...]
  if (!userTokenIsValid()) {
    await updateUserToken();
  }
  executeWhateverNeedsPermission();
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: I did actually tried that one before, and after some hours doing some tests I've been able to make it work, but it was way more complex than this:

    async function mainFunction() {
         //  [...]
         let userToken = oldToken;
         return userTokenIsValid().then(async (isValid) => {
               if (!isValid) {
                    userToken = await getNewUserToken();
               }
          }).then(() => {
               // Do the rest of the calls as before the patch.
          });
     }

Comment: But in the question `userTokenIsValid` is not returning any promise. So you can't use then/catch in the return of that function call

Comment: Your last comment helped me to find the issue, I was finally able to make it work. Thanks!